# Using NavigationRegion3D with Gridmap

Tags: godot, path-finding

So I was trying to do a grid based map with navigation on each tile. For my first try I had only one tile in the MeshLibrary. For some reason the navigation mesh was never being generated. So I reduced the cell size to 0.1 and scaled the inner mesh used to generate the navigation a little bit larger than the tile.

[image: Tile with helper mesh to generate navigation]

The I went to my scene, painted an area and selected Bake Navigation, under Navigation section of the GridMap. And my viewport look like this

[image: Weird divisions between each cell]

And my agent trace this route, even though there is nothing blocking the way
[image: Non direct route]

Am I missing something?

In the project the navigation cell heigth and size match the one I configured in the navigation mesh